# How to remove bullets from widget

Tags: theme-development, lists

I created a custom theme for my wordpress blog, and my widgets keep showing up in an unordered list form. I didn't program my widgets to appear this way. And I can't figure out how to remove the bullets from my widgets.

I tried editing the widgets.php file in the wp-includes folder by removing the beforewiget and afterwidget parameters but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I took a look at my source code and this is what's wrapped around the widgets.

```
<li id="categories-3" class="widget widget_categories"><h2 class="widgettitle">Categories</h2>
        <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/big-notch-updates/" title="View all posts filed under Big Notch Updates">Big Notch Updates</a> (20)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/music_news/" title="View all posts filed under Music News">Music News</a> (50)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/ramblings/" title="View all posts filed under Ramblings">Ramblings</a> (43)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/site-news/" title="View all posts filed under Site News">Site News</a> (14)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/stuff-i-like/" title="View all posts filed under Stuff I Like">Stuff I Like</a> (25)
</li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

So it looks like "catorgories 3" is what is making this a list. Is this something that is set in the wordpress files? can I modify it and set list-style to "none" through my theme css?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the bullet points to disappear, simply edit your themes style.css file. If you use a debugging tool you can find exactly where in style.css to edit. As you say, set list-style to none (though you might want to specify a class to ensure it doesn't effect lists where you do want bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want your widgets to show (if not list form - what) and can you show the code that you mention using to adjust them ("I didn't program my widgets to appear this way")?

see `widgets_init()`